# how to use RegularExpressionValidator on textbox

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, .net-1.1

I have an text box i need to validate so that the user can enter enter up to four character and they can be alphanumeric. I am using VS2003, .NET 1.1.

Please let me know what is the expression i should use to validate this condition
any help would be great. Thanks!

Tried like this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="wtxtTPP" tabIndex="2" runat="server" CssClass="text" Width="144px" MaxLength="4" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" style="z-index: 101; left: 208px; position: absolute; TOP: 16px" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,4})$" ControlToValidate="wtxtTPP" />
<input style="z-index: 102; left: 88px; position: absolute; top: 72px" type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit1" name="Submit1" runat="server">
```

Comment: Why do you use .NET 1.1? It's obsolete! Use at least .NET 2.0. Use can try free Visual Studio 2010 Express (which supports and 3.5 and 4.0). There are no reasons to stay on .NET 1.1.

Comment: http://www.aspdotnetkhan.com/RegularExpressionValidator.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As you said, use a Regular Expression Validator and set the expression to something like this:

```
^([\S\s]{0,4})$
```

Replace the 4 with your desired max length.

Update:

```
<asp:TextBox id="wtxtTPP" Runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
        ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,4})$" 
        ControlToValidate="wtxtTPP" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

This works just fine for me. I replaced your submit button with a normal asp.net button and simplified out all the unneeded stuff for the example.
In general, if you only have a one line textbox, you can just limit the text length with `MaxLength="4"` as you did. No need for a Validator.

Comment: hi Remy i tried like this   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ControlToValidate="txtTppCode" 
            ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{1,4})$ "></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: even if enter in the textbox as "12as"it is  displaying the error message

Answer (score 1):

Like @Remy said.

Also, the `{0,4}`  part of the Regexp means length should be zero to a max of four so will allow for zero-length, i.e. **no** input. Remember to use a RequiredFieldValidator if the number is mandatory or replace the zero with a minimum number of digits.

Comment: Actually, RegularExpressionValidator always passes on blank input, just like all validators except RequiredFieldValidator.

Answer (score 1):

```
       <table>
         <tr>   
           <td>E-mail Address:</td>
           <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txt_address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
             <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat ="server" 
              ErrorMessage="Please give Email Address! "
              ControlToValidate="txt_address"
              ValidationExpression="\S+@\S+\.\S+\w+"//example (example@yahoo.com)
              ForeColor="Red" >
             </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
```

---

```
    <table>
      <tr>            
        <td>
           <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_gender" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldVlidator2" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Please Choose your Gender" ControlToValidate="rbl_gender"
            ForeColor="Red" >
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

---

```
<table>
   <tr>    
     <td>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFeildValidator1" 
            runat ="server" ControlToValidate ="txt_name" 
            ErrorMessage="Please Insert Your name !" 
            ForeColor="Red">
         </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very small change in the ValidationExpression seems to make the difference between only sometimes working, and reliably working.
The following worked for me in development, but not in production:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "tbCarePlan" ID="revCarePlan" ValidationExpression = "^(.{0,4000})$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Max 4000 characters allowed." />
```

Replacing the ValidationExpression above with `"[\s\S]{0,4000}"` it now works reliably. Leave out the ^ and $ - the RegularExpressionValidator does not require this.